Azureml create environment using AzureML CLI v2 based on conda file and custom wheel
I want to create an environment using the AzureML CLI v2 by using the conda.yml and custom wheel file? I need an alternative of Environment.add_private_pip_wheel from the AzureML SDK v1.
Thank you

have tried anything? check the v2 docs from azure

Please share your environment details and what you have done so far.

Check below answer @Eddmik

You can directly add your wheel file link in the Conda file pip dependencies.
Here is the sample Conda file
name: pydata-example
channels:
  - conda-forge
dependencies:
  - python=3.8
  - pip=21.2.4
  - pip:
    - scipy==1.7.1
    - pandas==1.3.0
    - scikit-learn==0.24.2
    - adlfs==2021.9.1
    - fsspec==2021.8.1
    - xgboost==1.4.2
    - lightgbm==3.2.1
    - mlflow==1.20.2
    - azureml-mlflow==1.34.0
    - matplotlib==3.4.3
    - tqdm==4.62.2
    - joblib==1.2.0
    - jupyter==1.0.0
    - ipykernel==6.4.1
    - papermill==2.3.3
    - https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/76/9b/139b42e808e44571412e2b70f970085dc6bd215a46814f91503a75ff5be5/numpy-1.22.0-cp38-cp38-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl

Here, at the end i have given wheel file link.
Next use below code to create environment.
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential, InteractiveBrowserCredential
from azure.ai.ml import MLClient

try:
    credential = DefaultAzureCredential()
    # Check if given credential can get token successfully.
    credential.get_token("https://management.azure.com/.default")
except Exception as ex:
    # Fall back to InteractiveBrowserCredential in case DefaultAzureCredential not work
    credential = InteractiveBrowserCredential()


ml_client = MLClient(
    credential, subscription_id, resource_group, workspace
)

Now, create environment
env_docker_conda = Environment(
    image="mcr.microsoft.com/azureml/openmpi4.1.0-ubuntu20.04",
    conda_file="conda-yamls/your-conda-file.yml",
    name="docker-image-plus-conda-example",
    description="Environment created from a Docker image plus Conda environment.",
)

ml_client.environments.create_or_update(env_docker_conda)

This will create a job which makes new environment.
Make sure you giving correct wheel file according to the platform.
Refer this for more ways to build environment.
